# Automatically running app .py in in Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I have created a bot for my website and I currently host in on heroku.com. 
I run it by executing the command

`heroku run --app cghelper python bot.py`

This executes the command perfectly through CMD and runs that specific .py file in my github repo.

The issue is when I close the cmd window this stops the bot.py. How can I get the to run automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try:

heroku run --app cghelper python bot.py &